# How do I place a PRAW sort parameter as a function argument?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I want to perform sentiment analyses on various subreddits and consider both "new" and "hot" submissions. I'm able to do this in the following way:

```
# What I have
def new_submissions(sub):
   subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub).new(limit=100)
   for submission in subreddit:
      # Do stuff
   return new_stuff

def hot_submissions(sub):
   subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub).hot(limit=100)
   for submission in subreddit:
      # Do stuff
   return hot_stuff

new_submissions("subname")
hot_submissions("subname")
```

Here, "do stuff" involves 40 lines of identical code. I'd like to reference the "sort by" parameter for subreddits (e,g, .new(), .hot()) as a function argument as shown below:

```
# What I want
def submissions(sub, sortby):
   subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub).sortby(limit=100)
   for submission in subreddit:
      # Do stuff
   return stuff

submissions("subname", new)
submissions("subname", hot)
```

I have not had success in getting this to work. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is

```
def submissions(subreddit):
   for submission in subreddit:
      # Do stuff
   return stuff

submissions(reddit.subreddit("subname").new(limit=100))
submissions(reddit.subreddit("subname").hot(limit=100))
```

or if you want to do as you were looking for you could do:

```
def submissions(sub, sortby):
    method_to_call = getattr(reddit.subreddit(sub), sortby)
    subreddit = method_to_call(limit=100)
    
    for submission in subreddit:
        # Do stuff
    return stuff
    
# new and hot are strings to search for as attributes of the class
submissions("funnyvideos", 'new')
submissions("funnyvideos", 'hot')
```